# How to add delay after one full round of jmeter scripts run

Tags: jmeter

My requirement is like this:
1. Run one full round of test using jmeter 
2. Wait for 90 secs
3. Restart step1
4. I have to continue step1 and this entire process continues for 4 days.

Can someone help me how to add the delay after all the threads have been executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a thread group with 1 thread with a loop count of forever and and click "scheduler".  Set a start time and end time.
2. Put your tests within the thread.
3. Add a constant timer after the last test (still within the thread group though) and within thread delay, use 90000.  (This converts to 90 seconds)

Comment: But if i need to add loop count as well, then in that case I wont be able to check the forever checkbox

Comment: Why do you need a loop count if you are executing them for a set time?